# PHP preg_replace LINK only

Tags: php

I'm trying to preg_replace to detect a link in a string. Example below

```
$descriptionlink = "This is a test www.google.com";
$descriptionlink = preg_replace('/.*?\b((?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]\.[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]).*?/i', '$1', $descriptionlink);
```

It works great if there is a link in the string and echos out only the link like I want it. Now if the string is just text it will echo out the text. If it doesn't have a link I don't want to see the text in the string.

example of outputs I want

```
input - This is a test www.google.com
output - www.google.com
```

That above works great but it will do this and echo out the text below if no link

```
input - This is a test
output - This is a test
```

I want the output to be blank if it's just text.

Thanks

Comment: Preg replace it with nothing?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I mean I only want to show the link and not the text. The way it is now it shows both. Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example input with desired output?

Comment: use `preg_match_all("your regexp", "your string", $matches); print_r($matches);`

Comment: @ColeJohnson question has been update with desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$descriptionlink = preg_replace('/.*?((?:(?:https?):\/\/|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]).*?|.*/i', '$1', $descriptionlink);
```

Comment: in my test-env it does... maybe because the boundaries (line...)
... i edit the answer...

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you but works as is but has one problem if in the string example "you.hello" it will detect that as a link. Is there any way around that?

Comment: not really... the problem is, that we need ONE "thing" to identify an url... i've chosen ".[...]" as identifier... are all the urls of a special format? do they all contain "www." for example?

Comment: I only want it show link if www. or http:// and or both. It works fine like that but if two words are by each other with a period it detects it as a link.

Comment: time to ask me round for a coffee :D

Answer (score 0):

this... will replace all except the link...

```
$descriptionlink = preg_replace('/.*?\b((?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]\.[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]).*?/i', '$1', $descriptionlink);
```

Comment: capture-group 1 is the link... change it to whatever you want e.g. '<a href="$1">$1</a>'

Comment: If there is no link it will show the text then. How do I remove the text